# Magento 2.2.5 - Widgets and Blocks are not visible on home page

Tags: magento2.2, frontend, custom-theme

I have created a `custom theme` with a parent theme (`template monster`). Now, the home page of my store no longer has the widgets and blocks that were present in the parent theme. `The home page appears blank with header and footer only visible`..

The rest of the pages appear fine.. What could be the reason behind this?.

### **What I have already tried?**

- I have `deployed the static content` after deleting the
  `pub/static/frontend` directory.
- I have also `cleared my cache` multiple times but still no luck..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, Magento 2 themes call the static blocks using **widgets** and by default, **all the widgets are specific to a particular theme**.

So, when we create a new child theme based on a parent theme, the blocks called from widgets are not shown in the child theme.

If you want to display the same content in the child theme as the parent theme, you have to create new widgets same as the respective parent theme.

To do so, go to Content >> Elements (Widgets) and add new widgets.

I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Glad to know that I could help :)